# valgrind: tool 'memcheck' not installed

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm new to programming and am following the tutorials at http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html which shows you how to install valgrind. I've compiled the example program which should show memory leaks

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Warning: This program is wrong on purpose. */

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int height;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n");
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

    return 0;
}
```

but when i type

```
    $ valgrind ./ex4
```

i get the message

```
    valgrind: tool 'memcheck' not installed (/usr/local/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-darwin) (No such file or directory)
```

When i look in that directory there is no memcheck file. Has the installer not worked?

Comment: "*Has the installer not worked?*" looks like.

Comment: yep @alk was right. removed the latest version 3.9.0 and installed the one from the tutorial 3.6.1 and memcheck works correctly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Has the installer not worked?*" looks like. –  alk

yep @alk was right. removed the latest version 3.9.0 and installed the one from the tutorial 3.6.1 and memcheck works correctly. thanks –  j_hindsight